# Enviar un formulario que dentro tiene un multi select por medio de ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

estoy intentando enviar un formulario que dentro de el tiene los input de texto normales y ademas tiene un multiselect.
Los input de texto me los envia correctamente pero lo que selecciono en mi multiselect no los envia.
El multi select se carga con datos que yo traigo de mi base de datos para despues seleccionarlos

Este seria mi html:

```
<form  method="post" id="formulario">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Instituto</label>
        <input type="text" name="Instituto">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Nombre del Curso</label>
        <input type="text" name="NomCurso">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Descripcion del curso</label>
        <input type="text" name="DescCurso">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Duración</label>
        <input type="text" name="Duracion">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Cantidad de horas</label>
        <input type="text" name="CantHoras">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Cantidad de Creditos</label>
        <input type="text" name="CantCred">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">URL Asociada</label>
        <input type="text" name="URLAsoc">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Previas</label>
        <input type="text" name="Previas">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Categorias</label>
        <input type="text" name="Categorias">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputInstituto">Foto</label>
        <input type="text" name="Foto">
      </div>
      
      <select id="previas" multiple="multiple">
      </select>
      
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fecha</label>
      <input type="text" id="datepicker" width="276"  name="A_fnac"/>
     
      
     <script>
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4'
        });
     </script> 
    
      
    
  
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        
        <input type="button" value="Consultar" id="buttonDisplay">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="button" value="enviar" id="enviar">
    
      </div>
    </form>
```

mi envio por ajax seria el siguiente:

```
 $('#enviar').click(function(){
                     var url = "http://localhost:8080/edextweb/ConsultaPrevias";
                   .ajax({                        
                   type: "POST",                 
                   url: url,                     
                   data: $("#formulario").serialize(), 
                  success: function(data)             
                    {
                   }
                      });
                    });
```

Esto lo envio a un servlet yo imprimo los datos en el servlet me imprime todos bien menos lo que yo seleccione que me retorna null. Capaz el problema esta en que tengo que enviar el multi select en un dato aparte como un arreglo o  capaz estoy capturando mal en mi servlet el dato.

Comment: si y me devuelve lo que seleccione use este codigo: $('#previas :selected').each(function(){
  selected[i++]=$(this).text();
  })console.log(selected)

Answer (score 0):

simplemente debes agregar el atributo **name** a tu select multiple

```
<select name="previas" id="previas" multiple="multiple">
      </select>
```

y lo recibes de esta forma:

```
String[] previas = request.getParameterValues("previas");
if (previas != null) {
    for(String item: previas){
        String keyValue[]= item.split(":");
        out.println("Key: " + keyValue[0]);
        out.println("Value: " + keyValue[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: ah me habia olvidado de eso. Y para capturarlo en mi servlet seria de la siguiente manera? String[] cursos = request.getParameterValues("previas");  o no seria un arreglo eso?

Comment: exacto, pero lo debes procesar